# Parse latex macro trough sed

Tags: regex, parsing, latex, file-conversion, non-greedy

#### General overview

The goal is to match the content of all `\foo` occurrences to transform it into `<p>content of \foo</p>`.

#### The details

The goal is to match some LaTeX macro’s content from it opening bracket to the closing bracket.

But, then, two problems could occur. With greedy, if their is a closing bracket later after the macro ending in the same line like in `lorem ipsum \foo{dolor} sit amet et consectetur \bar{}`, then `s/\\foo{.*}/\1/` will match `dolor} sit amet et consectetur \bar{}`.

But, with non-greedy, I could match the closing bracket of a second macro inside `\\foo`.  As example with `lorem ipsum \foo{dolor \bar{sit amet} et consecteur} quia adipt` with `s/\\foo{.\{-}}/\1/` will match `dolor \bar{sit amet`.

In both little and greedy cases I fail to match the macro content and only the macro content.

#### The Question

So, how to match the macro content from the opening bracket to the corresponding closing bracket?

Alternative question: am I wrong to use sed, and then should I use a more dedicated LaTeX parsing tool?

Answer (score 0):

perl provides this functionality with a package Text::Balanced

I used perl to fix Latex output of the following form:

From:

```
\noindent {\tt// substitute into diffEQ }
\begin{dmath} \label{eq:3}
b \frac{d^{}\left(\text{a*(1-exp(-c*t))}\right)}{\mathrm{dt^{}}}+k a \left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-c t}\right)=F
\end{dmath}
```

To:

```
\noindent {\tt// substitute into diffEQ }
\begin{dmath} \label{eq:3}
b \frac{d^{}\left({a (1-\mathrm{e}^{-c t})}\right)}{\mathrm{dt^{}}}+k a \left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-c t}\right)=F
\end{dmath}
```

which yields:

[image: Rendered Latex]

with the following code:

```
perl -MText::Balanced -MData::Dumper -nlE '
    @brac = Text::Balanced::extract_bracketed($_, "{}", "^.*\\\\left\\(\\\\text");
    while ( defined(@brac[0]) ) {
#if(defined(@brac[0])) { print Data::Dumper::Dumper(\@brac)."\n" };
#print @brac[2], @brac[0], @brac[1];
    if(defined(@brac[0])) { modify_exp() };
    $_ = @brac[2] . @brac[0] . @brac[1];
    @brac = Text::Balanced::extract_bracketed($_, "{}", "^.*\\\\left\\(\\\\text");
    };
    print $_;

sub modify_exp {
    $brac[0] =~ s/\*/ /g;
    my @sub_brac = Text::Balanced::extract_bracketed($brac[0], "()", "^.*exp");
#print Data::Dumper::Dumper(\@sub_brac)."\n" ;
    $sub_brac[0] =~ s/\((.*)\)$/\\mathrm{e}^{$1}/g;
    $sub_brac[2] =~ s/exp//;
    $brac[0] = @sub_brac[2] . @sub_brac[0] . @sub_brac[1];
#print $brac[0];
#   $brac[0] =~ s/^{//;
#   $brac[0] =~ s/}$//;
    $brac[2] =~ s/\\text$//;
}
' "$1"
```

The commented lines were used to debug the code. The following link describes the package:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced

Answer (score 0):

sed can be used sometimes by using a trick where you use a regular expression that starts with the first bracket then includes as many characters that are NOT the closing bracket, "{[^}]*" for example. Finding the matching bracket can be a problem though. If, in the case of this question:

[Remove all occurrence of a command, preserving command argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062741/remove-all-occurrence-of-a-command-preserving-command-argument)

If the matching bracket is followed by a space, or maybe some other character, sed can work.